# Click event only for parent, not child

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I need add click event to my navigation but I want event only for parent, not submenu.

What I must do?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('nav ul li a').click(function() {
    alert('test');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Test</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Test</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/usbwLkjp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
           
  $('nav>ul>li>a').click(function(e) {
   
    alert('test');
  
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Test</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Test</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your css selector to target direct descendants like this

```
$('nav > ul > li > a')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use arrow `>` to target direct child

```
 $(document).ready(function() {               
      $('nav > ul > li > a').click(function() {
        alert('test');
      });    
 });
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/usbwLkjp/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

**This works for you :**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
           
  $('nav>ul>li>a').click(function() {
    alert('test');
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Test</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Test</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```